# BatchWriteItem method of AWS DynamoDB doesn't actually put items on DB

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

```
'use strict';

// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Set the region
AWS.config.update({ region: 'us-west-1' });

module.exports.updateTest = async (event, context, callback) => {
  // Create DynamoDB service object
  const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({ apiVersion: '2019-11-21' });
  if (!event.body) return;
  const { requests } = JSON.parse(event.body);

  const params = {
    RequestItems: {
      test: requests.map(({ param1, param2 }) => ({
        PutRequest: {
          Item: {
            param1: { S: param1 },
            param2: { N: param2 },
          },
        },
      })),
    },
  };

  try {
    await ddb.batchWriteItem(params);
    const response = {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        message: 'Test success',
      }),
    };

    callback(null, response);
  } catch (err) {
    const error = {
      statusCode: 400,
      body: JSON.stringify({
        message: new Error(err.message),
      }),
    };
    callback(error);
  }
};
```

When running the above Lambda function code on Postman, I can get the success status code, but the db is actually empty (the request data is also correct).
I am not sure why the db isn't filled with the request data.

Comment: Even if batchWriteItem does not fail, it may return UnprocessedItems (in case single item write fails).

Answer (score 1):

You return a success status code no matter the outcome of the BatchWriteItem. Wrap your BatchWrite request in a try/catch. Also, always ensure you return the correct response from Lambda, you only have a happy path which is the reason you're struggling to debug.